# What is primary and secondary clustering in hash?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash, quadratic-probing, linear-probing

What is the difference between primary and secondary clustering in hash collision management?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Primary clustering means that if there is a cluster and the initial position of a new record would fall anywhere in the cluster the cluster size increases. Linear probing leads to this type of clustering.

Secondary clustering is less severe, two records do only have the same collision chain if their initial position is the same. For example quadratic probing leads to this type of clustering.

Comment: I would like to add a clarification, (just in case the language of the answer created doubt). Secondary clustering happens in both Linear probing as well as Quadratic Probing, i.e. linear probing also suffers from secondary clustering.

Answer (score 139):

### Primary Clustering

1. Primary clustering is the tendency for a collision resolution scheme such as linear probing to create long runs of filled slots
   *near* the hash position of keys.
2. If the primary hash index is `x`, subsequent probes go to `x+1`,
   `x+2`, `x+3` and so on, this results in Primary Clustering.
3. Once the primary cluster forms, the bigger the cluster gets, the
   faster it grows. And it reduces the performance.

[image]

---

### Secondary Clustering

1. Secondary clustering is the tendency for a collision resolution scheme such as quadratic probing to create long runs of filled slots
   *away* from  the hash position of keys.
2. If the primary hash index is `x`, probes go to `x+1`, `x+4`, `x+9`,
   `x+16,` `x+25` and so on, this results in Secondary Clustering.
3. Secondary clustering is less severe in terms of performance hit than primary clustering, and is an
   attempt to keep clusters from forming by using Quadratic Probing.
   The idea is to probe more widely separated cells, instead of those
   adjacent to the primary hash site.

[image]

Comment: Were I to have ten more voting up right, I would do so.

Comment: @snr Thanks, I'm glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

**Primary Clustering:**
Primary clustering, refers to the phenomenon where collided keys form clusters or chains in adjacent slots during collision resolution. When a collision occurs and linear probing is used, consecutive slots are checked until an empty slot is found. If keys frequently collide and form clusters, it can lead to longer probe sequences and increased search times. Primary clustering can result in degraded performance as the clusters become longer and more keys are packed together.

**Secondary Clustering:**
Secondary clustering refers to the tendency for keys to form clusters in the probe sequence due to a poor choice of secondary hash function or step size in double hashing. When using double hashing, the secondary hash function is used to determine the step size for each probe. If the step size is not well-distributed or poorly chosen, it can lead to secondary clustering. Keys that collide at the same primary position may follow the same probe sequence and form clusters at different slots in the table. Secondary clustering can also impact the search performance and efficiency of hash-based data structures.